# Single Sign on between ASP.Net Web Forms using Forms Authentication and MVC using JWT Token

Tags: webforms, jwt, single-sign-on, forms-authentication

**Question:** I need to know if its possible to have both authentication methods "Forms Authentication" and "JWT Authentication" running in Parallel to have single sign on experience? Below is a short description of my requirement.

**Information:**

Website 1 = Asp.Net Web Forms (Forms Authentication)

Website 2 = MVC Web Application (JWT Authentication) on Same Domain.

**Requirement**

Website 1 needs to Generate a Json Web Token and Call Website 2 with it to open its pages seemingly on the clients browser.